# How are RGB values changed on an existing object?

Tags: color

I have an object with some color from an existing .blend file.  Where can the color be changed for this object?

[image]

Comment: There is probably a texture applied to this object which is why you see this color while the viewport shading is set to textured. You would need to change/remove the texture to change the color.

Comment: Thanks rjg.  I do recall, and have been seeing, that I had applied a partial reflective aspect to the object.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how with the present configuration (it looks like there was also a texture that had been applied):

Select the object.
Press Object button in properties.  ("Type of active data to display and edit:  Object")
In that same pane, scroll down to and maximize Display.  Current RGB is under Object Color:.

This can be done in either Object Mode or Edit Mode.